# Hadoop MapReduce MultipleOutputs - one in Mapper, one in Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I want to use multiple outputs in a Hadoop job in Elastic MapReduce. So, I set up `MultipleOutputs` in the `main()` method like so:

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(hadoopJob, "One",
    TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);

MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(hadoopJob, "Two",
    TextOutputFormat.class, NullWritable.class, Text.class);
```

I want "one" to contain output from the Mapper, while "two" contains output from the Reducer.

In the `setup` method for both the mapper and reducer, I call:

```
outputWriters = new MultipleOutputs(context);
```

In the mapper, I call:

```
outputWriters.write("One", nothing, sampleOutput, "One");
```

In the reducer, I call:

```
outputWriters.write("Two", nothing, new Text(thing.getStuff()), "Two");
```

Finally, in the `cleanup` method for both the mapper and reducer, I call:

```
outputWriters.close();
```

When I do this, I get a "file already exists" exception from the Reducer - it tries to recreate the output files that were already created by the mapper.

I can solve this by removing `outputWriters.close()` from the mapper `cleanup` method, but it introduces another problem: I don't get any of the mapper output.

What's the proper way to use `MultipleOutputs` with one in the mapper and one in the reducer? The JavaDocs do not mention this situation, and I haven't found anything useful on StackOverflow.

Update: This appears to run fine locally. However, if I try to run it in Elastic MapReduce with S3 output, I run into the "file already exists error." Any ideas on workarounds?

Comment: The code should work, can you please share the mapper and reducer code?

Comment: Please see my update: apparently this runs fine locally, but not in Elastic MapReduce. Also, I'd love to share the mapper and reducer code, but they are highly proprietary.

Comment: When you run it locally do the multiple outputs from the mapper and reducer end up in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, they do... which is what I would expect since I'm basically just supplying "one" and "two" as file names.